# Spotfire, filling empty / blank cells with absolute value from another calculated column

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

I want to fill a calculated column with the single value determined from another calculated column. So dummy_column2 must equal the single value determined from dummy_column1.

[image]

Comment: is value1 always the same in dummy_column1?

Comment: nevermind, in the meantime resolved it myself. thanks!

Comment: Please add your resolution as an answer and then you can accept it. It could help others!